# accessing to a specific cell value in excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i want to store a specific value of some cell in a variable which have my condition.
i am trying on [IMDB movie dataset](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/large_files/movies.xls).

```
import pandas as pd
file='movies.xls'
sorted=pd.read_excel(file,index_col='Language')
print(sorted.head())
```

for example i want to collect name of the movies which their Language is German.
i read function code of read_excel() and searched a lot but nothing helpful...
what should i do, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code do what i want...

```
import pandas as pd
file='movies.xls'
sorted=pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=0,index_col='Title')
var=sorted[sorted['Language'].str.contains("German")]
print(var.head())
```